# Highlighting a particular object, then removing the highlight upon clicking another of the same class

Tags: javascript, click

I currently have a timetable where if I click on a particular class element, it'll highlight. If I click anywhere else on screen, it'll no longer highlight. It works perfectly.

However, if I click a class element, then click another entry of the same class element, they'll both highlight. It's a problem in my code, but I don't know what to amend to change it.

Here is the JS (removed the irrelevant parts):

```
$(document).click(function() {  
    $('.outter').css("background-color","rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.8)");
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.outter', function(e) {
    $(this).css("background-color","#000");
});
```

So, basically it would affect the 'outter' class.
An example of the html:

```
<td id="mon-9">
    <p class="outter" style="background-color: rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.8);">
        Programming
        <br/>
        Lecture
    </p>
</td>
<td id="tue-9">
    <p class="outter" style="background-color: rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.8);">
        BPI
        <br/>
        Lecture
    </p>
</td>
```

So in this particular scenario, if I were to click either of these, they would show up black, and when I clicked off of them, they'd go back to normal. It works. However if I clicked one, then clicked the other, both would turn black. And not go back to normal until I clicked outside of a .outter tab. I'd give them individual ID's, but there are a LOT of entries. So that would be silly.

Is there a superior way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one instance to be highlighted:

```
$(document).click(function() {  
    $('.outter').css("background-color","rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.8)");
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.outter', function(e) {
    $('.outter').css("background-color","rgba(52, 73, 94, 0.8)"); //sets all elements to the initial color
    $(this).css("background-color","#000");
});
```

Simply set all elements to the initial color before changing the clicked element.
This is a quick and easy way (i.e. not recommended), not a superior one.